# Conmutativity and Asociativity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Groups by definition are associative, and may sometimes by commutative as is the case with abelian groups.

My question is the following: is there an algebraic structure or example where the operation is commutative, but not associative?

Comment: The set $\{0,1\}$ with the NOR or the NAND operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, [Jordan algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra).